# Помогите разобраться с кодом, выводится только одно действие

Tags: javascript, массивы

Хочу чтобы функция принимала массив элементов, выводила его и сумму всех его элементов. Когда делал отдельными функциями, то все работало. Пытаюсь все объединить в одну, но вывод происходит только массива, без суммы элементов. Помогите разобраться что я делаю не так.

```
function createArr(){
    var sum = 0;
    var emptyArr = [];
    for (var i=0 ; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        emptyArr[i] = arguments[i];
        sum+=arguments[i];
    }
    return emptyArr;
    console.log(sum);

}

console.log(createArr(1,2,3,4))
```

А если я захочу к примеру сделать какое-то действие с элементами массива, например возведение в квадрат и посчитать потом сумму получившихся элементов, как можно будет упростить код, чтобы sum не присваивать опять arguments[i]*arguments[i] а она брала значение уже готового массива emptyArr ?

```
function createArr () {
    var sum=0;
    var emptyArr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        emptyArr[i] = arguments[i]*arguments[i];
        sum+=arguments[i]*arguments[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
    return emptyArr;
}

console.log(createArr(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: Просто return sum; вместо return emptyArr;
    console.log(sum);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы в функции пишете:

```
return emptyArr;
```

После этой строки весь дальнейший код не выполняется.
Перенесите console.log(sum) выше ретерна.

2. хотеть, чтобы функция **выводила** или **возвращала** и массив элементов и сумму — хотеть две разные вещи.

Чтоб выводила достаточно написать:

```
function createArr(){
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i=0 ; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sum+=arguments[i];
        console.log( (i+1) + " array element = " + arguments[i]);
    }
console.log("sum = "+ sum);
}
```

3. Чтоб возвести в степень используют функцию [`pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) объекта [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

```
function createArr(){
var sum =0;
var array[];
for (var i = 0;i <arguments.length; ++i){
array [i] = Math.pow(arguments[i], 2); // в квадрат
sum += array[i];
console.log (array[i]);
}

console.log(sum);
}
```

Comment: А если я захочу к примеру сделать какое-то действие с элементами массива, например возведение в квадрат и посчитать потом сумму получившихся элементов, как можно будет упростить код, чтобы sum не присваивать опять arguments[i]*arguments[i] а она брала значение уже готового массива emptyArr ?         for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        emptyArr[i] = arguments[i]*arguments[i];
        sum+=arguments[i]*arguments[i];

Comment: @MaxM В вопросе есть кнопка "править" Воспользуйтесь ей для того, чтобы дополнить свой вопрос. Код в комментариях неудобно читать.

Comment: @MaxM Дополнил ответ

Comment: разобрался, благодарю)

Comment: @MaxM Не благодарите, поставьте галочку напротив ответа)).  Ознакомьтесь со справкой сообщества. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help там много полезного и в тур по сайту сходите   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Удачи))

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, либо как тебе в комментария описали, либо выводи объектом и потом бери , что тебе надо:

```
function createArr(){
    var sum = 0;
    var emptyArr = [];
    for (var i=0 ; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        emptyArr[i] = arguments[i];
        sum+=arguments[i];
    }
    return {
         emptyArr,
         sum
   };

}

console.log(createArr(1,2,3,4)) // { emptyArr: [1, 2, 3, 4],  sum: 10 }
```